# Regex - Jenkins check empty variable

Tags: regex, jenkins, conditional-statements, jenkins-plugins

I use a **plugin** with **Jenkins** to execute a job with a **condition step**.

I want to check if the parameter that I use is empty with this **regular expression**:

```
^$
```

And the **label field**:

```
${ENV,var="date.test"}
```

If the parameter is empty the job continue, but if has value it stop. But that does the opposite that I want.

Comment: It would be helpful to know *which* plugin this refers to. If this regular expression is doing the opposite of what you want, have you tried changing it to match a _non-empty_ value?

Comment: And the opposite of that? `/^\s*$`

Comment: That wasn't a complete sentence, so I'm not sure what you're asking. Do you want the opposite of what you wrote (a regex which matches a forward slash, a carat, followed by zero-to-infinite amounts of whitespace)? Or the opposite of an empty string, which would be _any_ text, i.e. `.+`?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried Regular Expression: `${ENV,var="date.test"}`
with an empty label and it works.